# When accessing ormlite repository in multple activities should there be multiple instances, a singleton, or what?

Tags: android, ormlite

I am using the sample provided by James Morgan's [DemoORMLiteAndroid](https://github.com/jamesemorgan/DemoORMLiteAndroid) which has one activity that instantiates a repository.

for reference

```
public class Repository {
    private Dao<Room, Integer> roomDao;

    public Repository(final DatabaseHelper databaseHelper) {
        this.roomDao = getRoomDao(databaseHelper);
        ...
```

and in Activity

```
public class RoomActivity extends OrmLiteBaseListActivity<DatabaseHelper> {
    private Repository repository;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.repository = new Repository(getHelper());
    }
        ...
        this.repository.clearData();
        ...etc..
```

How should the repository be accessed in other activities or classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this a great answer @Kevin but here it goes.

ORMLite has a couple of base classes which help with the bootstrapping of the Android databases.

- `OrmLiteBaseActivity`
- `OrmLiteBaseActivityGroup`
- `OrmLiteBaseListActivity`
- `OrmLiteBaseService`
- `OrmLiteBaseTabActivity`

Here are the Javadocs for them: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-android/

All these base classes do is provide utility methods which help manage a `DatabaseHelper` class which extends [`OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-android/com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.html).  You only want one instance of the helper class since it manages the connection to the database which gets passed in with the [`onCreate()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-android/com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.html#onCreate%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29) method.

The `onCreate()` method is what gets passed the Android `SQLiteDatabase` associated with the application which is needed for ORMLite to wrap inside its database connection code.

If you ask more specifically what you are trying to accomplish I'll edit my response to include more information.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I read the docs and everything works great.  My concern (unfounded?) is with creating more than one repository instance - will this cause performance problems or lead to lost connections to sqlite?

Comment: When you say "repository" are you talking about multiple SQLite databases?  If you are just talking about your helper classes, then as long as they all share the same `DatabaseHelper` instance, you should be fine.  It's when there are multiple connections to the database that problems happen.